# While using test driven development, should i remove previous tests if I know they work

Tags: tdd

I am currently doing a project for college and it requires me to write a simple program with a few methods. Every time I create a new method I copy the previous test, and then add that method to the test. Currently I have 4 tests with all 4 methods being tested in the fourth. Should I remove the first and second test which only test the first method, and then the first and second method. Sorry if this is confusing. Thanks

Comment: The question borders on opinion based. But as a general guide, the point of testing is to detect requirements not being met over the course of development. So removing tests "if you know they work" would fail to detect future changes in the code that cause things to no longer work (regressions). It's impossible to give specific advice about how many tests are enough and how many are too many without knowing more about your requirements and code, however.

Comment: Ok if its generally accepted to leave them in I will do that. Thank you

Comment: Each test should be small and focused, testing only one thing. I'd say stop the copy & paste programming, it will lead to bloated code that's hard to maintain. Ask yourself: what do you gain from keeping the same test code over and over? If it fails in one place, it fails in all of them, and if it passes, it passes in all places. So why keep the extra ones?

Answer (score 1):

That's not how test-driven development (TDD) is usually done. TDD usually serves two purposes:

- By writing the test first, you get feedback on the usability of your API design. A unit test *uses* the API of the System Under Test (SUT), so if the test is difficult to write, the SUT is difficult to use.
- The tests subsequently become artefacts that serve as regression tests.

Test code is also code, and comes with the same maintenance cost as regular code. It should be kept to the same standard as all other code, since you'll have to maintain it for the lifetime of the code base.

For that reason, rules about duplication, cohesion, coupling, etc. also apply for tests. In other words, don't copy and paste.

I've never heard about anyone following the process described in the OP.

Each test should test only one thing.